# Turning the screen off

Tags: android, onclick, screen

I am trying to make an app that  turn your screen off when you clicked a button. 
I have read about this

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
manager.goToSleep(int amountOfTime);
```

how do I achieve this? 
I am new in android studio so I am practicing this on my phone which also has a power button problem. Thankyou guys